# Conditional Join - Specific Column Select

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

I have tables like these:

```
Table Employee ( Emp_Id, Full_Name, ...)
Table Order ( Submitter_Id, Recipient_Id, ...)
```

Then say that I have conditional join like this:

```
select isnull(Emp.Full_Name, Emp2.Full_name) as Recipient  -- , other fields
from Order
    left outer join Employee Emp on Emp.Emp_Id = Order.Recipient_Id
    left outer join Employee Emp2 on Emp2.Emp_Id = Order.Submitter_Id
-- where clauses
```

**Brief explaination:** The query will return the name of recipient from specific order. An order may has recipient id being set, or using submitter id if the recipient is not set.

**The condition:** Both table `Order` and `Employee` has big amount of records inside, so joining them both is a costly operation. 80% - 90% of records in `Order` has `recipient_id` set, so joining to `submitter_id` can be useless operation. Using isnull as join condition can resulting in `index scan` (in my experience). Using `subquery` for column maybe help, but the cost can be high because the operation can be row-by-row.

Is there any conditional join for case like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your comment about the scan, that happens because using ISNULL() in the join manipulates the field, so it's no longer [SARGable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean). It may be faster to split this up, rather than try to do all the work in a single query. For example:

```
DECLARE @Recipient_ID INT, @Submitter_ID INT

SELECT 
@Recipient_ID = Order.Recipient_Id, 
@Submitter_ID = Order.Submitter_Id
FROM Order
-- where clauses

IF @Recipient_ID IS NULL

SELECT Emp.Full_Name
FROM Employee Emp
WHERE Emp.Emp_Id = @Submitter_ID

ELSE

SELECT Emp.Full_Name
FROM Employee Emp
WHERE Emp.Emp_Id = @Recipient_ID
```

EDIT based on comment:
Since there can be many orders, what about this? It is SARGable so should index well, and you're not querying the table multiple times.

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
COALESCE(Order.Recipient_Id, Order.Submitter_Id) AS EmployeeID
FROM Order
-- where clauses
)

SELECT Emp.Full_Name
    FROM Employee Emp
INNER JOIN cte on cte.EmployeID = Emp.Emp_Id
```

Comment: You are right, `isnull` making it non-sargable. However the query I mentioned is kind of reporting, so the resulting rows will be many (from many orders). So `if-else` ing using the parameter cannot be achieved. I can, though, joining using `UNION ALL`, though the performance is not yet tested.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO notifies of answer edits, so please check out what I added to see if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think your query will be treated as sargable, since coalesce can be treated like isnull as well (I may be wrong though). However I think it can works using temp table and not CTE, hasn't tried though.

Comment: Ack, you're right! I forgot that CTE executes during the SELECT, so a temp table will be faster. Another experiment is to try ...FROM Order INNER JOIN Employee Emp ON Emp.Emp_ID = CASE WHEN Order.Recipient_Id IS NULL THEN Order.Submitter_Id ELSE Order.Recipient_Id END. Since we haven't manipulated the field, and Employee is the table to search, I think it will remain SARGable. See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2010/02/02/a-case-study-in-sargability.aspx

Comment: Interesting, I haven't know that CASE WHEN can be treated differently with ISNULL. Will has this query tested then, to see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get better performance by using a `UNION`. This almost always works better in cases where I need to do a conditional join or filter.

```
SELECT Emp.Full_Name AS Recipient
FROM [Order]
    INNER JOIN Employee Emp ON Emp.Emp_Id = [Order].Recipient_Id
UNION --Or UNION ALL if you don't care about duplicates and want faster results
SELECT Emp2.Full_name
FROM [Order]
    INNER JOIN Employee Emp2 ON Emp2.Emp_Id = [Order].Submitter_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this change in the condition of the second join:

```
select isnull(Emp.Full_Name, Emp2.Full_name) as Recipient  -- , other fields
  from Order
    left outer join Employee Emp on Emp.Emp_Id = Order.Recipient_Id
    left outer join Employee Emp2 on Emp2.Emp_Id = Order.Submitter_Id
                                 AND Order.Recipient_Id IS NULL
   where clauses ;
```

and this, splitting the query into 2 parts, with `UNION`:

```
select Emp.Full_Name as Recipient  -- , other fields
  from Order
    INNER join Employee Emp on Emp.Emp_Id = Order.Recipient_Id
  where clauses
UNION ALL
select Emp2.Full_name as Recipient  -- , other fields
  from Order
    left outer join Employee Emp2 on Emp2.Emp_Id = Order.Submitter_Id
  where (clauses)
    AND Order.Recipient_Id IS NULL ;
```

---

And another idea. It looks simpler but I'm not at all sure about efficiency:

```
select Emp.Full_Name as Recipient  -- , other fields
  from Order
    left outer join Employee Emp on Emp.Emp_Id = 
                                    COALESCE(Order.Recipient_Id, Order.Submitter_Id)
   where clauses ;
```