# What is the difference between these extracting date method?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Assuming I have a table called MyTable, with a TimeStamp field "Created". I want only extract the Date part of this column, and in my research I found these alternatives:

```
SELECT created AS "Original",
       date(created) AS "DateFunction",
       created::date AS "DoubleColonCast",
       cast(created as date) AS "CastFunction",
       date_trunc('day', created) AS "DateTrunc"
FROM MyTable
```

1. In matter of [SARGability](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean), what is the preferred method?
2. What is the "SQL ANSI" (ie more portable) way?
3. What is the most common/used in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out `date(created)`, `created::date` and `cast(created as date)` are functionally equivalent.

If you want to be portable, use `cast()`. I think the `::` operator is more common in "Postgres land".
However, `date_trunc('day', created)` is **not** equivalent to the other expressions, because it returns a `timestamp` value, not a `date`.

Neither of those expressions will make use of an index on `created` - you would need to create an expression based index with the expression used in your queries. The `cast()` expression will be rewritten to `::` by the query optimizer, while `date(...)` will not. So if you create an expression based index, using `cast()` or `::` won't make a difference between the indexed expression and the one used in the query.

But if you use `date(..)` or `date_trunc()` you will have to use the same expression in your queries to make use of the indx.

Answer (score 2):

`created::date` and `cast(created as date)` are [syntactically equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537761/5059085) but `cast(created as date)` will be the most portable of them all as this is the most closest to ANSI SQL.

I don't believe any of them are **SARGable**, but `date_trunc('day', created)` can result in an extra cast operation to occur to [convert the date value to a timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) prior to applying it's logic, so your best bet all around, out of all them, would be to use `cast(created as date)`.

Answer (score 2):

All of these forms are equally good.

If any of these expressions appears in a `WHERE` clause like

```
WHERE date(created) = '2021-01-30'
```

then you have to create the index with exactly the same expression:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable (date(created));
```